# Java Socket not reading first byte of TCP packet data

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a simple socket client written on Android which communicates with a server:

```
Socket socket = SocketChannel.open().socket();
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.3",12345);//192.168.1.8
socket.connect(address);
DataInputStream input_stream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
int bits_read;
//we keep passing the same buffer to the read function until it returns -1 (EOF)
while((bits_read=input_stream.read(buffer))>=0)
{
     baos.write(buffer, 0, bits_read);
}
byte result[] = baos.toByteArray();
String response = new String(result, "UTF-8");
```

When I send a packet from the server with data, it gets received just fine, and the response variable contains the string "Thank you for connecting".  However, when I send a packet generated from my VPN service on Android containing the same data, the response variable contains the string "hank you for connecting" - ie the first character (and byte) is missing.

The hexdump of the packet from the server is:

```
98 d6 f7 5e 6e 0a b8 e8 56 37 1f e6 08 00 45 00 
00 4c c2 18 40 00 40 06 f5 30 c0 a8 01 08 c0 a8
01 0a 30 39 e8 c6 a8 e4 ec d8 aa 97 45 2b 80 18
20 2b 8b 87 00 00 01 01 08 0a 2e 66 a0 ea 00 61
d7 2c 54 68 61 6e 6b 20 79 6f 75 20 66 6f 72 20
63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6e 67
```

The hexdump of the packet from the VPN is (the Ethernet and frame headers are not actually sent through the VPN, but I've included them here to allow this to be imported into Wireshark and other tools for analysis):

```
00 00 DE AD 00 00 00 00 ED EE 00 00 08 00 45 00
00 40 25 B4 40 00 40 06 01 00 0A 00 00 03 0A 00
00 02 30 39 87 D2 14 04 0F 2C 3B AB 24 08 50 18
FF FF 5E 98 00 00 54 68 61 6E 6B 20 79 6F 75 20
66 6F 72 20 63 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6E 67
```

Both appear to be valid (using http://sadjad.me/phd/), with the only difference at the IP & TCP layers other than the source & acknowledgement numbers being that the latter doesn't have any TCP options (timestamps).  But how could this cause the client's socket to not read the first byte of the TCP data payload?

Comment: you mean android client sending data is not the same as sending from server?

Comment: the server is a separate machine.  The VPN on Android tries to emulate the server by inspecting the data passed to it on the TCP socket, and recreates a TCP/IP packet to send to Android through the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Did you try 'baos.flush'?